# Is it possible to replace specific characters inside a regex sequence?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Let's say I have the following text:

```
#Foo foo bar bar
foo bar foo
#bar Foo Foo
foo bar
```

Let's say I want to replace the spacebars with a `-` characters in lines that start with `#` character. So the output should be:

```
#Foo-foo-bar-bar
foo bar foo
#bar-Foo-Foo
foo bar
```

I know I can find those lines using this regex:

```
/^#(.*)$/gm
```

But can I actually alter those `$1` sequences in any way?

P.S. I'm using regex inside notepad++ to transform some data from excel into code (it's actually very convenient).

P.S.2 I also had to replace some tab characters in the text and after tinkering a bit with the answer by Avinash Raj, I found out that I can do that using this regex... Except it didn't work as intended, but Avinash Raj was kind enought ot help out once more with this regex.

```
/(?:^#|(?<!^)\G)[\S ]*\K\t/gm
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/3)

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Valid point, completely forgot about that (-_-; )

Comment: @AvinashRaj Added expected output to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think notepad++ would support [`\G`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). The anchor `\G` matches at the position where the previous match ended.

Regex:

```
(?:^#|(?<!^)\G)\S*\K[ \t]+
```

Replacement string:

```
-
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pM9pD0/5)

If you want to replace individual spaces with `-` then try the below regex,

```
(?:^#|(?<!^)\G)\S*\K[ \t]
```

Comment: Why `\S`? It just causes the pattern not to work with `#foo\t bar`. And why ` +`? That'll convert multiple consecutive spaces to one single dash.

Comment: @Rawing i think now it works for all the cases. or simply use `\h` instead of `[ \t]`

Comment: Thanks for the second example. Although the first one work on the test data provided in the question, when I altered it to fit my specific problem it didn't work. However the second example worked as intended with my alterations.

Comment: i think it's because of the tab characters present in your input file. a normal space won't match a tab character and `\s` would also match a new line character. So i added the both space and `\t` inside the character class.

Comment: Can you have a look at http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/1 ? I thought I managed to alter your regex to replace tabulators, but it doesn't seem to repect end of lines.

Comment: Why? what's wrong with this http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/2 ? If you `[^\t]*`, it would match the previous lines also.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I tried to replace just tabulators (spacebars excluded).